# Hot to make US postal addresses NOT a clickable link in mobile email programs

Tags: email, mobile, hyperlink

A lot of mobile email programs detect addresses when they appear within an email and then make a link out of them so the viewer can click the link and open a maps program.  Sometimes this is aesthetically not pleasing nor the intended behavior when including an address in an email.

Is there a way to prevent this and tell the email program ***NOT*** to make the address a clickable link.

Along those lines, email programs also detect dates/times and offer those up as clickable links which would open a calendar program.  Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe it is going to be implementation-specific. For example, with iOS, you can use something like `x-apple-data-detectors="false"`. But that won't work with other applications.

Comment: Myah... just tested that on my specific address element. Doesn't work unfort. e.g. <span x-apple-data-detectors="false">123 Abc Rd., City, ST 44123</span>